# GCD Euclid's algorithm as solution to the 2-buckets water puzzle

Tags: puzzle, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I completed an exercise on HackerRank, a site for programming exercises. The [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/die-hard-3/problem) has been inspired from Die Hard 3 movie. The original problem is like the following.

---

### The problem

You are given two buckets with capacity $5$ (bucket `A`) and $3$ liters (bucket `B`); you must obtain exactly $4$ liters of water (there is a fountain somewhere). The procedure is the following:

1. fill bucket `A` from the fountain completely: `A=5`,`B=0`
2. fill the bucket `B` with the water in bucket `A`: `B=3` and `A=2`
3. empty bucket `B`: `A =2`, `B=0`
4. fill bucket `B` with the water in `A`: `A=0`, `B=2`
5. refill bucket `A` from the fountain: `A=5`, `B=2`
6. fill bucket `B` with the water in `A`: `A=4`, `B=3`

Now changing the capacity values (let me call them `c1` and `c2`) of the $2$ buckets and the desired final value (let me call it `d`), sometimes this problem has a solution sometimes it doesn't.

---

### The solution

It turns out it has a solution when two conditions are satisfied (at least according to the HackerRank website and some users):

1. at least one of the buckets has a capacity larger than the final desired quantity: `c1>d OR c2>d`
2. calling `gcd` the greatest common divisor between `c1` and `c2`,  it must be that the reminder of the division `d/gcd` is `0`.

I discovered Euclid's algorithm and [this implementation](https://www.techiedelight.com/euclids-algorithm-to-find-gcd-of-two-numbers/) in the C programming language and everything worked out. The Euclid's algorithm to find the greatest common divisor, has the following procedure (let me assume `c1>c2` and let `r` be the reminder at each step of the division `c1/c2`):

```
while c2>0 do:
    r = c1 % c2
    c1 = c2
    gcd = c2
    c2 = r
return gcd
```

`gcd` variable will hold the value representing the greatest common divisor.

---

### My questions

However I am left with two questions, one about the problem and the other about Euclid's algorithm (they might be related):

1. why does the second condition (the one about the greatest common divisor) guarantee to tell if a solution exists for such a problem? Can anyone make the passage explicit?
2. Can you make explicit why Euclid's algorithm results in the `GCD`? It looks like magic to me.

Sorry if my question is quite long but I tried to give every piece of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All numbers are integers in the following unless stated otherwise.

---

**Answer to your first question**:

Assume that $\gcd(c_1,c_2)= a$ then by [Bézout´s identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) we have that there exists $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$
a=n\cdot c_1+ m\cdot c_2, 
$$

and the fact that $\frac{d}{a}$ leaves $0$ as a remainder can be phrased as

$$
d=k\cdot a,\qquad k\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Putting these two together means

$$
d= k\cdot n\cdot c_1+k\cdot m\cdot c_2
$$

to make this a bit cleaner let $\tilde{n}=k\cdot n$ and $\tilde{m}=k\cdot m$ so

$$
d=\tilde{n}\cdot c_1+\tilde{m}\cdot c_2, \qquad \tilde{n},\tilde{m}\in\mathbb{Z}
$$

So we could get $d$ as a linear combination of $c_1$ and $c_2$, translate this as *we could get $d$ by taking a number of times $c_1$ and a number of times $c_2$*. Observe that these *numbers* can be negatives as well so *put a couple of $c_1$s in and remove some $c_2$s* is also possible.

**Now for the second question**:

Assume that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. It is not hard to see that then 
$$
b>0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ b\mid a\Rightarrow \gcd(a,b)=b
$$

Another ingredient is the following fact, if $b\neq 0$ then

$$
a=b\cdot q+r\Rightarrow \gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)
$$

where $b>r$. I chellenge you to try to prove this :)

Having these in mind the [Eucledean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) is as follows:

$$
a=bq_1+r_1 \qquad 0\le r_1< b
$$

$$
b=r_1q_2+r_2 \qquad 0\le r_2< r_1
$$
$$
r_1=bq_3+r_2 \qquad 0\le r_2< r_3
$$

and so on. This will terminate after a while since the remainders are getting smaller and smaller and at some point you will reach $r_{n+1}=0$.

This gives us the following chain of equalities:

$$
\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r_1)=\gcd(r_1,r_2)=\ldots=\gcd(r_{n-1},r_n)=\gcd(r_n,0)=r_n
$$

I hope this helped a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The first part is very clear. The second a little bit more challenging: I have to read more carefully also because you have challenged me :)
  But what it the meaning of $b \mid a$ in this case?

Comment: Ok my issue was to realize $gcd(a,b)=gcd(b,r)$. Is the following correct? $$gcd(a,b)=k_1\cdot a+ k_2\cdot b = k_1\cdot (q\cdot b + r )+ k_2\cdot b = (k_1 \cdot q + k_2)\cdot b + k_1 \cdot r$$

but this is a linear combination of $b$ and $r$ hence it is also $gcd(b,r)$. Something like that?

Comment: More easily actually: if $d$ divides $a$ then it must divide also $b+qr$